# SSH asks to add same host as known a second time

Tags: ssh

One of my colleagues recently tried to ssh into a server using the same domain as before, but he got asked by the ssh-client if he wants to add the host to the list of known hosts. As he would ssh to the server for the first time.

I took a look at his `known_hosts` file and he has the public key of that server 3 times. Using:

```
ssh-keygen -f /path/to/his/known_hosts -H -F <hostname>
```

I found that first two keys were pared with the hash of the server IP and domain. The third key it's paired with a hash that's different from the other 2 and I assume has been added when he was asked to add the host as known again.

Does anyone know if using the same domain as before why would the `ssh-client` not recognize it in the `known_hosts` file, ask for it to be added again and add a different hash for the same domain?

Comment: What do you actually mean by "domain" here. Is he SSH-ing inte _different_ server that happens to share the same domain name part of their host names? Also, has he changed SSH configuration settings in his `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: There is no ~/.ssh/config, no changes to files in /etc/ssh/ either.
We have an internal DNS server and configured to have something like host1.mydomain.com point to the internal IP of that server.

Comment: Has the IP changed? It is NOT only relevant which domain name is used.

Comment: The IP did not change. Also I do not have this problem, but I am using another machine.

Comment: SSH servers may offer multiple key types (rsa, dsa, ecdsa, ed25519) which a client config change may have caused a new key to be seen. Or, there could be a man-in-the-middle attacker. Hard to say with the information provided.